# SQL is there a way to select all values that are the beginning of a given value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select everything from a database that is the beginning of a given value. Here's what I mean:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+
| ID           | url                   |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 1            | https://example.net   |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 2            | https://example.com   |
+--------------+-----------------------+
| 3            | https://example.org   |
+--------------+-----------------------+
```

I have a string that is `https://example.com/something`. Is there a way to get `https://example.com` from that by selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take **BaseUrl** before that `/`.

```
SET @text := 'https://example.com/something';

SELECT LEFT(@text, POSITION('/' IN REPLACE(@text, '//', ''))+1) AS BaseUrl
```